# Upgrade MongoDB version on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, version, upgrade

I have MongoDB version 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 20.04.

How can I upgrade the version to be 4.2+?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
    wget -qO – https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.2.asc | sudo apt-key add –
    echo “deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.2 multiverse” | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.2.list
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade mongodb-org
```

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: Nothing, seems that the execute was successful, but when I restart machine and check again mongodb version, it is 3.6.8 again.

Comment: Ok try sudo apt-get --only-upgrade mongodb-org